# how can i access arrays outside a while loop

Tags: c, arrays

how can I access an array outside a loop which was populated inside a while loop ?

**Main.c**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "Definition.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

extern int Readline(),CountWord();

char Line[500];  /* one line from the file */
char myFileList[300][MaxLine];
char myFileList2[300][MaxLine];
char myFileList3[300][MaxLine];
char myFileList4[300][MaxLine];

int NChars = 0,  /* number of characters seen so far */
    NWords = 0,  /* number of words seen so far */
    NLines = 0,  /* number of lines seen so far */
    LineLength;  /* length of the current line */ 


void *ThreadTask(void *threadarg)
{
//receive array
//match each element with file name in directory
//perform counts on each file
//print store or return values 

//printf("%s",myFilesList);

}    

FILE *filep;

int main(int argc, char **argv)  
{
    int i = 0;
    filep = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!filep){
        printf("No %s such file found\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }
    while ((LineLength = Readline(filep))!=0) //here in this loop I split a big file into 4 arrays depending on the number of lines(240). How can I access these newly created arrays outside the while loops. I need to pass them to individual threads as arguments. 
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<60){
        strcpy(myFileList[i], Line);
        printf("%s\n", myFileList[i]);
        i++;
        }           

        if(i>=60 && i<120){
        strcpy(myFileList2[i], Line);
        //printf("%s\n", myFileList2[i]);
        i++;}


        if(i>=120 && i<180){
        strcpy(myFileList3[i], Line);
        //printf("%s\n", myFileList3[i]);
        i++;}

        if(i>=180){
        strcpy(myFileList4[i], Line);
        //printf("%s\n", myFileList4[i]);
        i++;}


    }       

    fclose(filep);      
}
```

Readline.c

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int Readline(FILE *filep)
{
//Please implement your code here
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while (!feof(filep) && i<MaxLine){
        ch = fgetc(filep);
        if (ch == '\n'){
            break;
        }           
        Line[i] = ch;           
        i++;

    }

    Line[i] = 0;
    return i;
}
```

whats the easiest way to pass the four arrays created in the while loop to threads as arguments? I every time I try to print out the arrays outside of the while loop there is nothing and when I try to print them out inside the while loop but outside the if loops then they only display the 1st line 60 times.

Comment: Why don't you prepare a simple small file with data and use that, and present the output for printing inside the ifs and outside. (I'm not sure what's wrong.) One remark though: The eof() test is only meaningful after an attempt to read has failed. If you test first and read then, you have an invalid char (usually -1) in your buffer. That shouldn't be the general problem here, but it's still a bug. The canonical way is to declare ch, somewhat unintuitively, as int and test for the value EOF _after_ getc(). feof() is only good to tell the failure reason.

Comment: You are allocating `300` just to use `60` of each, why?

Comment: Your arrays are global, they are already accessible to everyone. Just make sure threads start AFTER filling data, and you're good. You probably have trouble filling, not reading them.

Answer (score 0):

If using PThreads use the last parameter of [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) to pass an argument to the tread-function.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the pointer to the array to ReadLine... It's good practice to pass the maximum length, too, to avoid buffer overflows errors.

```
#define MAXLEN 240

char Line[MAXLEN+1];

while ((LineLength = Readline(filep, Line, MAXLEN))!=0)
{
  ...
}


int Readline(FILE *filep, char *Line, int maxlen)
{
   ...
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but it seems like the array is only being stored while inside the while loop, when I try to print outside the while loop I get an empty array, however inside the while loop it prints out just fine. Any other suggestion?